# jpeg file not recognized as image in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have made a validation for image field as

```
'avatar' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:1000',
```

it works for png image but fails if i upload jpeg image with message `The avatar must be an image`. Any thoughts?
Here is form view

```
    {!! Form::open(['route'=>['admin.myprofile.update',$admin->id],'method'=>'put','files'=>true]) !!}
...
            {!! Form::file('avatar', ['class' => 'dropify btn-warning','data-default-file'=>$admin->avatar?asset($admin->avatar):'']) !!}
..
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: can you show more detail?

Comment: $this->validate($request,[
           /****/
            'avatar' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:1000',
        ]);

Comment: Please edit your question and add your `form` code too, also you don't need to use `mimes` if you use `image` in the validation rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your rule validation is overlap each other you can change it to this and see the result:

```
'avatar' => 'nullable|mimes:mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:1000'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `image` validator is kind of buggy here. Avoid using this validator. In the accepted answer even if you remove the `mimes` types validator and use the `image` validator only as following

```
'avatar' => 'nullable|image|max:1000'
```

Then for some jpeg images, it will work fine but for most images, it will not work.

Correction for the accepted answer. There is a typo there as `mimes:` is repeated twice. Bellow is the corrected code

```
'avatar' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:1000'
```